# Report generation by week between the given dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to split a report by work week, and work week is from Monday to Sunday. Let's say I give the `start_date` as `01-12-2012` and `end_date` as `29-12-2011`. Now, I want to split 1st-4th as week1, 5th-11th as week2, 12th-18th as week3, 19th-25th as week4, 26th-29th as week5.

I have tried the following code, but not getting the accurate. Any modification or suggestion would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT 
    ta.account, ta.customer, 

    isnull(sum(CASE WHEN (datepart(wk, ta.dt)- datepart(wk,dateadd(m, DATEDIFF(M, 0, ta.dt), 0))+ 1) = '1' 
THEN amount END),0) AS "1",

    isnull(sum(CASE WHEN (datepart(wk, ta.dt)- datepart(wk,dateadd(m, DATEDIFF(M, 0, ta.dt), 0))+ 1)= '2' 
    AND (datepart(dw,ta.dt)= 1)
    THEN amount END),0) AS "1",

    isnull(sum(CASE WHEN (datepart(wk, ta.dt)- datepart(wk,dateadd(m, DATEDIFF(M, 0, ta.dt), 0))+ 1)= '2' 
    AND (datepart(dw,ta.dt)<> 1)
    THEN amount END),0) AS "2",

    isnull(sum(CASE WHEN (datepart(wk, ta.dt)- datepart(wk,dateadd(m, DATEDIFF(M, 0, ta.dt), 0))+ 1)= '3' 
    AND (datepart(dw,ta.dt) = 1)    
    THEN amount END),0) AS "2",

    isnull(sum(CASE WHEN (datepart(wk, ta.dt)- datepart(wk,dateadd(m, DATEDIFF(M, 0, ta.dt), 0))+ 1)= '3' 
    AND (datepart(dw,ta.dt)<> 1)    
    THEN amount END),0) AS "3",

    isnull(sum(CASE WHEN (datepart(wk, ta.dt)- datepart(wk,dateadd(m, DATEDIFF(M, 0, ta.dt), 0))+ 1) = '4' 
    AND (datepart(dw,ta.dt) = 1)        
    THEN amount END),0) AS "3",

    isnull(sum(CASE WHEN (datepart(wk, ta.dt)- datepart(wk,dateadd(m, DATEDIFF(M, 0, ta.dt), 0))+ 1) = '4' 
AND (datepart(dw,ta.dt) <> 1)   
    THEN amount END),0) AS "4",

    isnull(sum(CASE WHEN (datepart(wk, ta.dt)- datepart(wk,dateadd(m, DATEDIFF(M, 0, ta.dt), 0))+ 1) = '5' 
    AND (datepart(dw,ta.dt) = 1)    
    THEN amount END),0) AS "4",

    isnull(sum(CASE WHEN (datepart(wk, ta.dt)- datepart(wk,dateadd(m, DATEDIFF(M, 0, ta.dt), 0))+ 1) = '5' 
    AND (datepart(dw,ta.dt) <> 1)   
    THEN amount END),0) AS "5"

FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM tablename
     WHERE dt >= '12/01/2011 00:00:00' AND dt < '12/26/2011 00:00:00'
    ) ta
GROUP BY 
    ta.account, ta.customer
```

The desired o/p is:

Account       Customer    Week1     Week2     Week3    Week4    Week5

For the above given dates,
week1 should be 1st-4th
week2 should be 5th-11th
week2 should be 12th-18th
week2 should be 19th-25th
week2 should be 26th-01st(of Jan 2012)

As I do the report on every Monday, I want the total amount from Monday to Sunday as one week.

There may be a case that, the customer may not have any usage. So, in that case I want it to be as 0.00 as week5 in the above example.

Hope you understand my question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SET DATEFIRST 1    
SELECT tn.account, tn.customer, SUM(amount), DATEPART(ww,tn.dt) WeekNumber
FROM tablename tn
WHERE dt >= '12/01/2011 00:00:00' 
      and dt < '12/26/2011 00:00:00'
GROUP BY ta.account, ta.customer, DATEPART(ww,tn.dt)
```

[DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) returns an integer that represents the specified datepart of the specified date. In this case number of week in the year.

[SET DATEFIRST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) sets the first day of the week to a number from 1 through 7 where 1 is Monday, 2 - Tuesday and so on.

Comment: Hi, I almost got. But I want to print the week of the month not the year and my week starts from Monday to Sunday. Let's say for this December, the week1 should be 1st to 4th and week2 should be 5th to 11th and so on. Finally, week5 should be 26th to 31st.

Comment: @sandysmith Sorry, I didn't quite understand your comment. In my example `SUM` are calculated by weeks and for the1st week `amount` will be taken just for rows with dt >= '12/01/2011 00:00:00'. Do you want these Weeks as columns? It would be great if you provided desirable outputs in your question (you can edit it).

Comment: I just edit my question. You are right. I want the o/p as week1 to week5 as columns.